# Trying to change the format to mm/dd/yyyy in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am copying the below value from my tool to excel.
**Fri May 05 00:00:00 EDT 2017**
I would like to change this to mm/dd/yyyy format. I tried 'format cells' and explored date, text, custom, general options, but nothing is working. Please guide me. I am thinking of writing a formula where i can make it look like may 05,2017 and from here i can change the date format.

Comment: Write your formula; you may have to wrap your formula in the `DATEVALUE` function.  That should work

Comment: trying the datevalue(trim()) function but no luck so far

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show your attempt (working or not)? Do **not** put it into a comment.

Comment: @deeps I would not expect `datevalue(trim()) ` to return anything.  It is not a valid formula.  There is no argument.